# nginx index directive does not work

Tags: nginx

In the following configuration snippet for nginx:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:433;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        server_name example.com;

        root /var/www/example.com;
        index index.html;
        error_page 502 = @fallback;
        error_page 404 = @not_found;

        location / {
            #try_files /index.html $uri =404; # A
            try_files $uri =404;              # B
        }

        location /service/ {
            rewrite ^/service/(.*)$ /$1 break;

            proxy_set_header X-Load-Balancer "a";
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.100:42424;
        }

        location @fallback {
            try_files /502.html =500;
        }

        location @not_found {
            try_files /404.html =500;
        }
}
```

Why does A correctly serve index.html (which is located in /var/www/example.com/) but B doesn't and results in the 404.html page being served instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try_files` directive processes each term in order, until it finds a file that exists.

If the file `/var/www/example.com/index.html` exists, the first term in case (A) will always be successful, and the URI will be internally changed to `/index.html`. The `index` directive is not involved. Also, case (A) will **always** return the `/index.html` file.

In case (B), `try_files` is looking for files only, and **not** directories. If you want `try_files` to match a directory and process it with the value of the `index` directive, use a term with a trailing `/`. For example:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Gotcha! I remember reading that the `index` directive works on URIs with trailing slashes, but I did not immediately understand that the actual serving was implemented by `try_files`. It makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: You do not need `try_files` to implement `index`. But if you do have a `try_files` statement, you need to add the `$uri/` term, otherwise `index` will be disabled within that block.

Comment: Oh, ok. Is that specified in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: Index is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index).

Comment: I really don't see how I would have gathered the information you provided from the documentation, which I had already read.